# gcm-calibrate without hardware sensor

Tags: gnome, brightness, monitor, gnome-color-manager

My monitor won't allow me to set the contrast when using DVI. And ubuntu/gnome won't allow me to set it via software without some fancy color calibration sensor. on `system settings > color` the "calibrate" is disabled. if i run it manually via `gcm-calibrate --device="xrandr..."` it forces me to use a sensor.

Is there any way to calibrate my monitor color/brightness/contrast without using a VGA cable or a sensor?

I don't mind editing the ICC profile by hand if that is possible (i.e. it is a text format) and if i can have a fast preview... but so far i don't even know where to start. the system settings>color screen do not offer the slightest hint of where the icc files it is using are. or how to export/save them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/659440/61218 Still no luck!