# calibrate screen, gnome color manager (calibrate button disabled)

Tags: nvidia, gnome, colors, gnome-color-manager

I recently noticed that the white on my ubuntu is not exactly white, its redish. Now since I found about it, it is bugging me. How can I calibrate my screen so that white on my ubuntu is same as white on my windows.

I tried gnome color manager but cant calibrate. I am not able to use any of the color calibrators?

I have nvidia 820M and intel 5500HD graphics.

Comment: I supposed you looked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/424732/how-do-i-calibrate-colors-without-extra-hardware-like-dccw-exe-on-windows .  Did you try to import your pick of ICC profiles, as suggested by @g_p ? You can do so from your Ubuntu system settings / Device Color Profiles.

Comment: have you tried `dispcalgui` instead of the default gnome color manager ?

Comment: Gnome color manager's calibration functionality requires a colorimeter, that's why the button is disabled.

Comment: This might help explain it: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/172whn/is_the_button_for_calibrating_a_monitor_disabled/

Answer (score 8):

Since you have an Nvidia GPU, you can use Nvidia X Server Settings to create your own color correction settings.

1. Install Nvidia X Server Settings:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
   ```
2. Launch:

   ```
   $ nvidia-settings
   ```
3. Find the Color Correction tab for the display you wish to calibrate (under "GPU 0 - (Quadro FX 2700M) -> DFP-0 - (LGD)" in the following screenshot):
   [image]
4. Select the color channel you wish to change using the Active Color Channel selector, then modify the Brightness, Contrast, and Gamma as you see fit.

Comment: The OP has intel card too. And I also have Intel card. It would be better if you can edit the answer to address Intel cards too

Comment: I have the same software for nvidia-settings and it doesn't show the option to change the colors. Nvidia over-delivering, as always (not).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `redshift`? Although designed for a different purpose, it does have features for setting the colour temperature of your screen.

```
sudo apt-get install redshift
```

This is my config file ~/.config/redshift.conf:

```
[redshift]
temp-day=5700
temp-night=4600
brightness-day=1.0
brightness-night=0.75
gamma=0.8
adjustment-method=vidmode
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=63.81415
lon=20.41742
```

`redshift` modifies the colour temperature by the time-of-day. If you set temp-day and temp-night to the same colour, you disable this feature. Perhaps that solution will work for you.

If you do want the colour temperature to change at night, you would obviously need to change lat/long.

If you want `redshift` to autostart at login, select Applications/System tools/Preferences/Startup applications/Add. Name: redshift. Command: /usr/bin/redshift.

Comment: Hmm, I have heard and used redshift before. Willing to know about a more convenient way of adjusting gamma. Just like the alternative of that tool found in Windows. Can you give all the options Redshift supports?

Comment: Can't list them here, but you'll find them at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/redshift.1.html.

Answer (score 1):

Best to just create a color profile.  Locate a cheap colorimeter (I have an old spyder 3 unit), they are all plenty good to set the white/black points and get a reasonable color profile (don't read too much in to the marketing that you need the newer stuff for newer screens).  Use dispcalgui to create the profile.  Then just point the gnome color profile setting to the icc file.  you can also set it on the command line if you use something like kde that doesn't seem to natively support icc profiles. I have this in my ~/.bashrc file so it is set no matter what I might be doing:

dispwin ~/WE40UX8310.icc >& /dev/null