# How to calibrate colors without a colorimeter?

Tags: system-settings, color-management, gnome-color-manager

Although this question has already been asked a few times before ([without hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424732/how-do-i-calibrate-colors-without-extra-hardware-like-dccw-exe-on-windows), [nvidia-settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659440/calibrate-screen-gnome-color-manager-calibrate-button-disabled?noredirect=1&lq=1)), either the question was not answered clearly, or it relied upon a graphics card that is not available on systems such as my own. Is there a way to calibrate the color profile in Ubuntu without a GPU or colorimeter?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. You can use displaycal-gui to create a synthetic ICC profile, then either double click the .icc file to install it or use the Profile Loader bundled with the application.

However, displaycal-gui doesn't let you edit curves of your color profile as far as I know. You'll be using something like this:

[image: Create synthetic ICC profile screenshot]